# Find (and delete) all files that do NOT contain certain patterns (PLURAL) in their name

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, filenames, gnu-findutils

I'm looking for an easy way to find and delete all files in a directory and all its subdirectories that do NOT contain certain strings in their name.

I tried starting with the find command first:

```
find . -type f \! \( -name "TMP_TGL_2" -o -name "PRES_SFC_0" \)
```

But it doesn't seem to exclude the second string pattern. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You don't test whether the file names **contain** strings, you test whether the names are exactly the strings you specify here.

Comment: Why not simply `find . -type f ! -name "TMP_TGL_2" ! -name "PRES_SFC_0"`? And anyway, _doesn't seem to_ is not very helpful. Please edit your question and show what file names are not excluded that you think should be.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet That works. I wrongly assumed I had to "-or" it but it turns out that does something different.

Comment: @glades Simple first order logic: `NOT (a OR b)` is the same as `(NOT a) AND (NOT b)`. Note that the backslash in `\!` is useless and that `find . -type f ! \( -name "TMP_TGL_2" -o -name "PRES_SFC_0" \)` should also work. If it doesn't there is probably something else that you don't show us...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -type f ! \( -name "*TMP_TGL_2*" -o -name "*PRES_SFC_0*" \)
```

The wildcards round the patterns will insure that they match files which *contain* those strings (otherwise they would only match files with names that are identical to the strings).